# Funcion para crear trayectos

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla de la que saco una serie de paradas de autobús correspondientes a una línea, en la tabla hay los siguientes campos, las paradas se corresponden con un id_linea.

```
id_linea
id_parada
descripción linea
tiempo desde la parada anterior
```

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `pasa_por` (
  `id_linea` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_pasapor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parada` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tiempo desde la parada origen de la línea — en minutos.',
  `incremento` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `discrecional` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pasapor`,`id_linea`,`id_parada`,`incremento`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `pasa_por_unique_id_linea_km` (`id_linea`,`time`),
  KEY `pasa_por_ibfk_1` (`id_linea`),
  KEY `FK_pasa_por_2` (`id_parada`),
  KEY `FK_pasa_por_3` (`discrecional`),
  KEY `pasa_por_index_linea_parada` (`id_linea`,`id_parada`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128646 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Necesito poder crear trayectos con esas paradas, de modo que se creen los trayectos 1ª --> 2ª, 1ª --> 3ª, así sucesivamente hasta la última, después hacer lo mismo con la 2ª parada, es decir crear el trayecto 2ª --> 3ª, 2ª -- > 4ª, luego 3ª --> 4ª, 3ª --> 5ª....

Para esto he pensado hacer una función recursiva, pero no se por donde empezar, los datos están en una BD mysql y utilizo php.

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. ¿Eso es todo lo que tienes en la tabla? ¿Cómo calculas el tiempo desde la parada anterior? Lo propio sería tener otros campos en la tabla que gestiona la relación, como `llegada (DATETIME)`, `salida (DATETIME)`. Sabiendo a qué hora se llegó y se salió de cualquier parada, podrás calcular lo que sea, entre una parada y cualquier otra. Dicho eso, tampoco queda muy claro qué es lo que quieres lograr. Un ejemplo, basado en datos reales y lo que estás intentando, sería de gran ayuda para comprender mejor el contexto y el problema.

Comment: en la tabla que me dan solo aparece el tiempo entre trayectos, es decir si sale de la parada 1 a las 8:00 y en la parada 2 tengo 30, quiere decir que llega a las 8:30. La parada 1 siempre tiene 0

Comment: Lo que quiero conseguir es trazar los trayectos y sus tiempos de una linea con n paradas a partir de una array con todas las paradas de esa línea, es decir tengo que conseguir pares de paradas así origen1->destino2, origen1-> destino3, y así sucesivamente con todas las paradas para conseguir todos los trayectos posibles en esa línea.

Comment: No lo entiendo del todo. Ayudaría que pongas un ejemplo con los datos que tienes y cómo están diseñadas las tablas. Como ya dije, en vez de trabajar con duración, es mejor trabajar con fecha/hora de llegada y de salida. Son datos reales, a partir de los cuales puedes calcular lo que sea: cuánto tiempo duró en una parada, cuánto tiempo duró el trayecto total, en qué parada estuvo más tiempo, etc, etc, etc. Los campos calculados son contextuales, y no deberían ser almacenados en casos como estos, sino calculados.

Comment: Usa la pregunta para explicar el contexto, no los comentarios. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar la estructura de la tabla y un ejemplo de datos en ella. Para mostrar su estructura puedes ejecutar `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;` en el SGBD.

Comment: es una tabla llamada pasa_por donde se dan de alta las paradas de una determinada línea. El campo tiempo lleva el tiempo arrastrado, es decir la 1 vale 0, la 2 30, la 3, 75 y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al final donde estará el tiempo total del trayecto. Lo que euiero conseguir es generar los trayectos posibles entre paradas y los tiempos a partir de esa tabla.